# Get/open temp file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to do something like the below. What function returns me an unique file that is opened? so i can ensure it is mine and i wont overwrite anything or write a complex fn generate/loop

```
BinaryWriter w = GetTempFile(out fn);
w.close();
File.Move(fn, newFn);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two methods for this:

- [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=VS.100).aspx)

  This will create a temporary file and return its name.
- [Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=VS.100).aspx)

  This will use a cryptographically strong, random string as file name and won't create the file for you.

Usually the first method suffices; the documentation for GetRandomFileName says:

> When the security of your file system is paramount, this method should be used instead of GetTempFileName.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is the [TempFileCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection.aspx) class.  It provides an IDisposable wrapper much like what is suggested in the docs for Path.GetTempFileName().

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use the [GetTempFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method to obtain a fairly unique temporary file name.