# Pass a MemoryStream object to a FileStream object

Tags: c#

I have a `MemoryStream` object, and i want to write it to a file and pass it as a parameter in the following `passFile` method. The `passFile` method currently accepts a `FileStream` object as a parameter, but is there a way where i could convert the `MemoryStream` object to a `FileStream` object? Help

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

public void passFile (FileStream file){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot cast it: `MemoryStream` and `FileStream` are siblings in the inheritance hierarchy, they cannot be cast to one another.

If the method cannot be re-written to take a `Stream`, you could [write the content of the `MemoryStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624188/335858) into a [temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2741306/335858), and then open a `FileStream` based on the content of that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Stream` abstraction, and pass any type of stream as `FileStream`, `MemoryStream`, etc...  for sample:

```
public void passFile(Stream stream)
{
   // process stream
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do i then convert a Stream to a File ? i am looking at the link @dasblinkenlight has given, and still can't figure out what is the `File` object so i could use it in the method.

Comment: Look at the dasblinkenlight link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file/8624188#8624188 ... there is a way to convert between them.