# Modify Application.StartupPath

Tags: c#, command-line, path

I am creating a file:

```
 String strPath = Application.StartupPath;
....
 string filePath = strPath + "\\Books" + ".zpl";
```

later on the path is send to command line to be copied to parrallel port (for printing..)

```
string command = "copy " + filePath + " lpt1"; //prepare a string with the command to be sent to the printer
// The /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo sinf = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

sinf.UseShellExecute = false;
sinf.CreateNoWindow = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); // new process            
p.StartInfo = sinf;//load start info into process. 
p.Start();
```

My problem is that  `Application.StartupPath`  may contain folder names with spaces (like e.g: Document and Settings).
In that case I have to put quotes on that folder names.
However  `Application.StartupPath`=> the address path resulting will be known after the installation of the program in the client, so I don't if and how many folder names need `quoting`

Any ideas?

Comment: Pretty unclear why String.IndexOf() is slowing you down.  There's otherwise no point to it, just *always* quote the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the quotes are not always required the do not harm => use them all the time.

BUT you should not use `Application.StartupPath` for such a task.
You can use something like the following:

```
var dir = Path.Combine(Environment
    .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyProgram");
if(!Directory.Exists(dir))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
var path = Path.Combine(dir, "books.zpl");
```

In the startup path you will NOT have write privileges if you are not an admin and the application is installed to "program files".

Comment: what to you suggest to use? A predefined path?

Comment: Maybe a temp file is even better for your case, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741306/get-open-temp-file-in-net